# dopostback not defined when using ie11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

Today I have upgraded my browser to IE11.

The problem is that I have a ASP.NET site, that fails with dopostback not defined when clicking a linkbutton from the production site.

When debugging in VS2012 I get "this page can not be shown".

Do I really need to downgrade to ie10, to debug in ie again ?

I'm using Win7 on my local PC

Answer (score 1):

See here for fixes:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

Basically this is fixed in ASP.NET 4.5 but there is also an older patch for all versions of the .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

Problem occurred cause of: There is a bug in the browser definition files that shipped with .NET 2.0 and .NET 4, namely that they contain definitions for a certain range of browser versions. But the versions for some browsers (like IE 10) aren't within those ranges any more. Therefore, ASP.NET sees them as unknown browsers and defaults to a down-level definition, which has certain inconveniences, like that it does not support features like JavaScript.

I also had same problem,I followed this article, and I'm sorted. Go through below link, It would help for sure.

[fix](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BugAndFixASPNETFailsToDetectIE10CausingDoPostBackIsUndefinedJavaScriptErrorOrMaintainFF5ScrollbarPosition.aspx)

Comment: install-package App_BrowsersUpdate causes VS2012 to freeze when loading the project.

Comment: kb 2600088 says it can't be installed on my pc

Comment: KB2600088 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer

Comment: Maybe this will work <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">